# Showing that $||(x, y)||_1$ := $|x| + |y|$ is a norm

Tags: normed-spaces

Show that $||(x, y)||_1$ := $|x| + |y|$ is a norm on $\mathbb R^2$ := {($x, y$) : $x$ ∈ $\mathbb R$, $y$ ∈ $\mathbb R$}

I've came across this problem but I don't really know what to do. 
Like, if $||(x, y)||_1$ := $|x| + |y|$, doesn't that directly mean that it's a norm since it is always defined for any values of $x$ and $y$? Please I need help. Thank you

Comment: What are the axioms of a norm? You have to check them.

Comment: I don't know these axioms, the professor didn't tell us about them in the lecture. Can you please tell me what are they?

Comment: See the already given answer by Fred.

Comment: Okay, thank you so much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to show:

1. $||(x,y)||_1 \ge 0.$
2. $||(x,y)||_1 = 0 \iff (x,y)=(0,0).$
3. For $ \alpha \in \mathbb R$ we have $|| \alpha(x,y)||_1 = |\alpha | \cdot ||(x,y)||_1.$
4. $||(x,y)+(u,v)||_1 \le ||(x,y)||_1+||(u,v)||_1.$